# How can I get the model of phone using the twitter api?

Tags: json, twitter

This article describes how tweets were used to track owners of iphones and android phones: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2597269/Maps-reveals-Android-poor-people-iPhone-owners-live-affluent-areas.html#ixzz2xxLiOXhS

But when I look in the API docs I don't see the phone model data. How can I get the model of phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1) Never believe anything you read in the Daily Mail.

Step 2) Take a look at the metadata which comes with every [Twitter timeline request](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline).  You will see a `source` parameter on every Tweet.  This tells you the name of the app the user used to Tweet.

Step 3) Work out which apps correspond to which Operating System.  In some cases it's easy - "Twitter for iPhone" is pretty obviously for iPhone.  How about "Falcon Pro"?  You'll need to investigate to see if it's an Android client.

You almost certainly won't be able to see if it's an iPhone 5 or Android 4.4 - but you should get a rough idea of which of the major Operating Systems was used for each Tweet.